# Any way to make interactive graphs in LibreOffice like Google Doc's Trend chart?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc, google-docs, trendlines

Google Docs has a nice trend viewer that can be created just like any other chart:

[image: Google Trends chart]

Is there any way to get an interactive graphic like this in OpenOffice?  Manually adjusting the axes is really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive? No. Openoffice is designed for print / static type outputs, whereas Google Docs is a step away from that and expects all of its users to be on the Web. This component in particular is a Google Charting piece that Google leverages on its other properties including Analytics and Finance.

Comment: "Designed for print output" doesn't mean it can't be easy to use.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an interactive data analysis tool. Google Docs makes sense for this, and there are plenty others out there. I would even bet that OpenOffice has plugins or modules that will add interactivity to its charts... actually, since OOo is open-source and the Google Charts API is public, a decent developer could create a module that leverages this exact component to give you the interactive chart you desire. Seems like a pretty straightforward and potentially simple project for someone already familiar with OOo's code.

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing I'm asking about.